# SonarCloud - No scan results appearing for Javascript for maven / bitbucket project

Tags: javascript, maven, sonarqube, bitbucket, sonarcloud

I might be missing something obvious, but I can't seem to get scan results for javascript to appear in SonarCloud. The repository is 95% an angular app with 5% java code. The java code scan **is** appearing in SonarCloud, but really I only need to scan the javascript in the angular application.

So clearly we are connected to SonarCloud, but nothing appears for the javascript.

I added `<sonar.language>js</sonar.language>` to the pom.xml file, which has had the effect that no scan information at all appears in SonarCloud, presumably because this property cancels scanning any language **other than** javascript, and the javascript scan isn't configured correctly.

I just want to scan the angular project and report results in SonarCloud. Either by scanning the `dist/portal` directory where the angular project is built, or by scanning the underlying Typescript files in `src/app`.

It's fine if the java code is also scanned.

Thanks for any help or pointers you can provide.

- ALM used: Bitbucket with Maven
- Languages of the repository: java, javascript (only need to scan the javascript)
- Error observed: No scan results for javascript appearing in SonarCloud

The directory structure of the repository is:

```
    - src
        - app
        - [rest of angular code]
    - e2e
        - [testing files]
    - deploy
        - pom.xml
        - [java code for the deploy]
    - bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

This is the pipeline.yml, and the step that uses maven to run sonarcloud:

```
          caches:
            sonar: ~/.sonar/cache
          steps:  
            - step: &buildArtifacts
                name: Build and test
                image:
                  name: [[NAME]]
                  aws:
                    access-key: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
                    secret-key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
                caches:
                - maven
                - sonar
                script:
                - source prepare_environment.sh
                - mvn -e clean verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar
                artifacts:
                - artifact/**
```

And this is the properties inside the `pom.xml` in the `deploy/`directory:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <sonar.language>js</sonar.language>
        <sonar.sources>${project.basedir}/../dist/portal</sonar.sources>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Best option for scanning JS/TS is a custom Pipe.**

If you don’t care about the Java code and just need to scan the Javascript and Typescript, then using the [scanner for CLI](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/) is probably the best bet, and even more specifically, using the [scan pipe](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/integrations/ci/bitbucket-pipelines/) is easiest to configure on Bitbucket Cloud. You don't need to use Maven at all.

In your `bitbucket-pipelines` YAML file, remove (or comment out) the reference to `org.sonarsource.scanner` in your `&buildArtifacts` step:

```
mvn -e clean verify # org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar
```

Then create a new step to run the pipe:

```
    - step: &buildAndTestSonarCloud
        name: Analyze with SonarCloud
        caches:
          - node
          - sonar
        script:
          - npm update && npm install  
          - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:0.1.5
            variables:
              SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
              EXTRA_ARGS: '-Dsonar.sources=src/app'
              SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS: -Xmx512m
              DEBUG: "false"
```

You might also need to expand memory available for the step with something like this:

```
definitions:
  services:
    docker: 
      memory: 2048
```

Finally, call your step:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *buildAndTestSonarCloud
    - step: *buildArtifacts
```

That should work. You should be up and running there on the JS/TS.

If you also want to run unit tests *and* have sonarcloud track your test coverage, add this below your `npm update` line:

```
- npm run test -- --code-coverage --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox
```

And these `EXTRA_ARGS` configured for your file structure:

```
'-Dsonar.tests=src -Dsonar.test.inclusions="**/testing/**,**/*.spec.ts" -Dsonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info'
```

That worked for me and should handle the full configuration.

Note: This is not going to look at Java code in your repository. If you *do* need Java code also scanned, a more complex Maven implementation is what you will need.